# video feed from imutils to tensorflow

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and opencv.

I am using [imutils](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils) package for streaming video from webcam for achieving higher fps. I want to input these frames to a CNN inception model which I have trained through transfer learning. Currently I am doing the following :

**initializations** :

```
from imutils.video import WebcamVideoStream

stream = WebcamVideoStream(src=0).start()
```

**Snippet to feed each frame** :

```
while True:

 frame=stream.read() 
 cv2.imwrite('pic.jpg',frame)
 im_data=tf.gfile.FastGFile('pic.jpg', 'rb').read()
 text=run_graph(im_data, labels, FLAGS.input_layer, FLAGS.output_layer)
 cv2.putText(frame,text,topLeftCornerOfText,font,fontScale,fontColor,lineType)
 cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
 key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
 fps.update()
 if key == ord('q'):
    break
```

I read each frame from queue, save it as '**pic.jpg**' and then pass the filename as an argument to `tf.gfile.FastGFile` to feed it to the function `run_graph` which predicts it as content of variable `text` which I display on my image.

This works, but it is very slow because of the writing and reading. What would be an efficient way to do this or how to directly input video streams into tensorflow.

`cv2.VideoCapture(0)` blocks the main thread until a frame is read from the camera. `imutil` does this in a separate thread and adds the frame to queue, then reads the frame from the queue in a separate thread whenever `read()` is called, this gives high fps. If there is some other code that can do the same, is compatible with tensorflow and can let me add a text on the picture to show the prediction frame by frame, that would also be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

referred from [datascience.stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19896/tensorflow-and-opencv-real-time-classification).

**Modified code**:

```
while True:

 frame=stream.read() 
 frame = cv2.resize(frame, (299, 299), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
 numpy_frame = np.asarray(frame)
 numpy_frame = cv2.normalize(numpy_frame.astype('float'), None, -0.5, .5, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
 numpy_final = np.expand_dims(numpy_frame, axis=0)
 text=run_graph(numpy_final, labels, FLAGS.input_layer, FLAGS.output_layer)
 cv2.putText(frame,text,topLeftCornerOfText,font,fontScale,fontColor,lineType)
 cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
 key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
 fps.update()
 if key == ord('q'):
    break
```